# How to find the secondary inductance of the Motor if Ld, Lq, flux linkage, frequency, speed, rotor, and voltage details are known?

Tags: motor, inductance, ac-motor

Precisely, the question. Is there any formula for this?

Comment: Is there a diagram you can post that shows the position of Ld and Lq and, can you confirm that it is a single phase motor?